# Worst case memory access in 80x86 assembly

Tags: assembly

In a 80486 computer, what is the worst case (include the fetch) number of memory accesses of this instruction:

```
add dword [x],0x123FA4
```

It is known that an opcode with no operands is two bytes in length.

Comment: probably you should try reading the Intel manuals and try to solve your problems yourself rather than posting random questions awaiting explanation of some weird thing.

Comment: the answer is 8 but i dont know why

Comment: it is not homework
i am learning for a test!!!!!

Comment: If you opened your book and figured this out yourself, you would gain a much higher understanding of what is going on, rather than just have someone tell you the answer to a _test_.

How about you sign the test 'StackOverflow' when you hand it in instead of your own name.

Comment: @Pax: would you really call this a _basic_ question? Considering it depends on the alignment of the instruction bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From memory, the instruction has an opcode byte ("add"), an address mode byte, an offset for x (4 bytes) and the constant (4 bytes) ==> 10 bytes.    I assume the 486 fetches 4 bytes at a time from memory with a bus address aligned to 4 byte DWORD boundaries.   So 10 bytes arguably takes 3 memory reads (= 10/4 rounded up) no matter where you place them.  Howevever, if the opcode byte is place in the last byte of a DWORD, the remaining 9 bytes span 3 more DWORDS to the total number of reads can actually be 4.

To do the add, the location X must be fetched.  Assume X is split across a DWORD boundary -> 2 reads.   Adding the constant happens inside the CPU, and the sum is written back across that same DWORD boundary split --> 2 writes.

So, the worst case should be 8 memory operations.